# Can I create a mock TCP server, similar to Wiremock for http requests

Tags: api, http, server, tcp, mocking

**Background information:** I have a register(using windows) that's used by fast food restaurants, and after I create an order, the register will send a request to the payment device(where users can tap their creditcard and pay for the food). When the register and payment device communicate through http, I have set up a mock server using WireMock to mock the payment device.

**Problem:** The issue is that not all payment devices use http. Some payment devices use TCP connection. Is there a tool out there that lets me create a mock TCP end point server? Or is there a way for me to create this mock TCP server so my register can talk to it?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In case this is still relevant to you and you have not found an answer, [mountebank](http://www.mbtest.org/docs/protocols/tcp) could be of help in your  use case for mocking TCP Servers.

If you are familiar with Wiremock's stub creation using their standalone JAR, mountebank works in somewhat similar manner. You create a stub by posting the details of a stub to the mountebank's REST server.